# unable to install wine in ubuntu14.04 and getting dependencies error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wine

i am using ubuntu 14.04 .i am trying to install wine but getting following dependencies error .
I tried sudo apt-get install wine
I got this error-

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not installable or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

then tried - sudo apt-get install wine1.7 and get this -

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-amd64 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1)
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried  then `sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386` but got this -

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7-i386:i386 : Depends: libmpg123-0:i386 (>= 1.13.7) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1:1.13) but it is not installable
                     Depends: libopencl-1.1-1:i386 but it is not installable
                     Depends: ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 (>= 1.0) but it is not installable or
                              libopencl1:i386
                     Recommends: libcapi20-3:i386 but it is not installable
                     Recommends: libgif4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libosmesa6:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libpcap0.8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libsane:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libv4l-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: p11-kit-modules:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: unixodbc:i386
                     Recommends: wine-gecko2.34:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: wine-mono4.5.4:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I also tried -

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and got this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

then tried `sudo apt-get autoremove`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

and then tried sudo apt-get update

and tried again but no luck .
 and output for - `dpkg --print-architecture`is `amd64`
and for `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` is `i386`

please help !!!
Thanks in advance !!